# Expand truncated object view in python heapy / guppy

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heapy

I have a memory leak in my django app and used heapy to debug the memory stack. I believe I finally came to the cause of the problem. Now I need a way to expand that truncated representation of the string, so I can identify the source. Is there a way to do this in guppy?

> Set of 1  object. Total size = 4831096 bytes. Index     Size 
>   %   Cumulative  %   Representation (limited) 0  4831096 100.0
>   4831096 100.0 **u'< {"to...]}}}]}}}'**

This is what I doing currently

```
from guppy import hpy
h = hpy()
print h.heap()[0].byrcs[0].byid[0]
```

Comment: Hi Jabb, did you figure out how to accomplish this? I also see truncated version which suggests using '_.more' to view in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `.theone` attribute to see the full representation, eg

```
h.heap()[0].byrcs[0].byid[0].theone
```